FLutter Android toolchain issue, JDK version Issue, version change issue
Hey I am getting an issue regarding flutter JDK version issue. Somehow I changed that when I upgraded my jdk to version-21, But there I got many issues regarding this update. and Now I have installed the jdk v-20, and have changed the env variables as well. But still my android studio not working!
Tried-
Reinstalling flutter/android studio/jdk
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
X Cannot execute C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\java to determine the version
While I am getting this in my cmd -
C:\Users\User>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20
and I have tried every thig literally everything but I am struck here.
enter image description here
have a look this is my env variable
enter image description here
Jdk path
enter image description here
enter image description here
I Just want that that this X Cannot execute C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\java to determine the version
to be changed to my jdk-20
I appreciate any help reguarding this.

try this and replace the path to a jdk like version 17 or less flutter config --jdk-dir "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11". I heard the latest jdk is not yet compatible with many latest  gradle and flutter versions, although android studio comes with them by default

try this and replace the path to a jdk like version 17 or less flutter config --jdk-dir "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11". I heard the latest jdk is not yet compatible with many latest gradle and flutter versions, although android studio comes with them by default

That worked, Thanks a lot sir.

You need to mark it as an answer
